# Vim's syntax highlighting considers a lambda (->) in Java an error

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-java

I am using Vim to program in Java 8, and am having a problem with syntax highlighting.

A new feature in Java 8 is lambda support, which resulted in the creation of the arrow operator: `->`.  Vim does not recognize this as a valid operator in a *.java file.  As such, it highlights this operator in bright red to draw attention to the "syntax error."  (Of course, this really is valid syntax.)

Is there a way to update Vim's "dictionary" of allowed operators and/or fix the syntax highlighting to avoid this issue?

The first two lines of `:version` state:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
>
> Included patches: 1-52

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### 2016 update

The Vim syntax file [was updated for this in v7.4.649](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f3c2afb77f8b1f2591337fcaa90ba0fb45365cbc#diff-eda7359419b4ac52df5a77541cf1e82f) (March 2015); so if you have this patch you don't need to do this.

The easiest way to fix this is probably by downloading the [newer `syntax/java.vim` file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/java.vim) and putting it in `~/.vim/syntax/java.vim` so it will override the default `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/java.vim`. You will also need to symlink `html.vim` for this to work as `java.vim` depends on this:

```
ln -s /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/html.vim ~/.vim/syntax/
```

---

#### Original answer

My `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/java.vim` has this:

```
syn match javaError "<<<\|\.\.\|=>\|||=\|&&=\|[^-]->\|\*\/"
```

See the `[^-]->` part? That causes the error highlighting.

You can override this rule by adding a `~/.vim/after/syntax/java.vim` file,
with the same pattern minus the lambda syntax:

```
syn clear javaError
syn match javaError "<<<\|\.\.\|=>\|||=\|&&=\|\*\/"
```

---

And for bonus points, we can add this line to highlight this as a function:

```
syn match javaFuncDef "[^-]->"
```

Consider filing a bug report. `:help bug-reports` explains how. There seem to be more (new?) constructs that are highlighted as an error, such as the `...` in `public static void main(String... args)`.

Comment: The matching for the bonus points does not check if `java_highlight_functions` has been enabled. If you are neurotic about consistency, you should probably check it before the `syn match` call:

`if exists("java_highlight_functions") | syn match javaFuncDef "[^-]->" | endif`

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to edit the default syntax file. The [vim-java](https://github.com/vim-jp/vim-java) plugin has support for this. Just install like any other plugin and the lambda operator will be highlighted correctly.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I don't see any code for it, and the [only commit I see](https://github.com/vim-jp/vim-java/commit/a21e5ee04576920e7083bf274aa4aca3409c57b4#diff-6cf7f9192680eaee9b1e199a1dfe5702) only removes the `->` from javaError with the message "Don't match javaError if it's a lambda symbol" (but doesn't add highlighting as a function).

Comment: @Caspetsmoker You're right. Just removes the error message. But I prefer like this.

Comment: I see that the runtime files have been updated in March 2015 btw, and that the repo you link to doesn't have many fixes that this updates introduces. FYI :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Nice. Did work as expected. Thanks =)